# How do i insert crystal report parameters in my SQL SERVER?

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2012, crystal-reports

I'm having a problem that how i will insert those parameters in my SQL SERVER after the Print Button is Clicked [Crystal report sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0e9h.png)

Answer (score 0):

Parameters are inserted in Crystal Reports - not SQL Server. 
Read the following link to see how -

https://www.kb.blackbaud.com/articles/Article/54043